# How does a class know the sizeof its members?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, sizeof, member

To skip some repetition here and narrow down the question to more specific, I will cover very quickly what I believe I understand.

A class is a pointer to different sizes of variables, called members. If the members are of different sizes, they are all allocated the same space of the sizeof the biggest member.

So in memory they are all the same sizes, thus my question: **How does a class know the sizeof its members?**

Example:

```
class foo
{
    short a = 99;
    int b = 88;
};

int main()
{
    foo f;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(f); i++)
        cout << (int)((char*)&f)[i] << " ";

    return 0;
}

// Output:
// 99 0 -1 70 88 0 0 0
// 
// where -1 and 70 are random bytes in memory
```

So complimenting my main question for those who didn't understand: How does **f** know when reading member **a** how to return a **short** (99 0) and not an **int** (99 0 -1 70)?

Comment: A class is not a pointer, and what follows makes no sense. You seem to be confusing classes and unions.

Comment: Stop casting. It's tricky enough if you know what you're doing, and you clearly don't. What you do is Undefined Behavior, and you cannot deduce anything from the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a task for the compiler and this is why the class has to be a complete type in this and similar cases, that is the compiler need this:

```
struct foo {
     short f;
     int b;
};
```

...or similar. When the type is complete the compiler can decide the size of the type and the offset of it's field and other thing it need's to know in some situations.

Without a complete type definition it would not be able to:

1. Accept declaration of a variable of `foo` type (ie the `foo f;` statement).
2. Accept a `sizeof(foo)` expression
3. Create pointer to members.
4. ... and more.

Since you couldn't declare the variable `f` without having complete type you wouldn't be able to get it's size or access it's members.

If on the other side you use an incomplete type. That is the compiler only has seen:

```
struct foo;
```

Then the compiler can not do anything that requires a complete type, but it can for example have pointers to `foo`, but it cannot look inside it, allocate it or do pointer arithmetics on it.

Comment: Thank you for this complete and detailed answer, provided with clean examples. I understand.

Answer (score 2):

The class does not need to know, your compiler does.

> If the members are of different sizes, they are all allocated the same space of the sizeof the biggest member.

This is simply not true. Just imagine a class with two members, first a big struct of 20 doubles and second a single char.

Answer (score 0):

You have some misconceptions, but one thing you might try in order to get a better understanding is to use the `offsetof( typename, membername )` macro from `<stddef.h>` on some simple structs.  Maybe try printing `offsetof( foo, a )`, `offsetof( foo, b )`, `(uintptr_t)&f` and `(uintptr_t)&f.b` to see how the compiler is finding `f.b` given an address for `f`.  In a class method, `f` is named `this`.

The way a class works is like that (plus they also have a table of pointers to their virtual functions, and when you call one, you’re really calling the first, second or third function in that table).  The way single inheritance works is that all the base class’ members and methods appear first, at the same offsets, in the derived class.  The way multiple inheritance works—is complicated.